# Vue data "counter" does not iterate upon site switch (but does count up in the console)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am animating a Landing Page, basically like a slideshow (A little more complex as I am moving displacement Filters in PIXI). After passing 3 seconds the slide should change.

The "slides" have labels which are pulled through prismic in the `created()` method. Those should always show an `active` class if their index equals the current `this.i`

```
<a v-bind:href="'#'+title" 
   :class="{ active : index == j }" 
   @click="change(index)" 
   v-for="(title, index) in titles" 
   :key="`title-${index}`" 
   v-bind:data-hover="title">{{title}}</a>
```

My data looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    ..
    i: 1,
    j: 0,
    ..
  };
}
```

I run a timed slider controlled by GSAP and trigger the `next()` function `onComplete`.

```
next() {
  this.j += 1;
  if (this.j >= this.items.length) {
    this.j = 0;
  }
  this.change(this.j);
},
```

Now this all works fine until I switch sites and go back again (Either back button or a direct link).

I can output the value `this.j` and it will always reference the right value in the `console`. 
But if I have a look into the VUE's chrome Dev Tools `this.j` shows me a `0` and does not update. Therefor the labels also don't adjust themselves.

What am I doing wrong here? Eager to learn. Has it to do with the reactiveness?

Comment: I am not sure I got your problem, but if you have some issues on updating the ui, then instead of using the data fields directly in the UI, use a computed property such as `computed: { jcomp: function() { return this.j } }`, use the `jcomp`inplace of `j`.

Comment: agree with @gokublack, computed would be better. The reason is that when you leave your Vue instance, the dom tears down the watchers for the data property being tracked. Then, when you come back to the page, it initializes the data to its hard-coded value, makes any changes to the data based on created/mounted methods, and creates new watchers. 

You can read more on that here, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies. So what I would need to do is replacing this 

`:class="{ active : index == j }"` with `:class="{ active : index == jcomp }`

But don't I need to declare the jcomp value somewhere when it iterates? Cause if I switch pages and go back I have the same problem again.

Counting the value of `j` up in the `next()` method my `j` goes up (in the console) but my jcomp stays at the value it was left at. 
`jcomp - 2  ------   j - 3`
`jcomp - 2  ------   j - 4`

Comment: I could not really find a way to get this done. So I ended up adding two invisible buttons to the Dom which I trigger on my method which in return trigger the original method. Surely not the best way but it works.